# How to custom list item with 2 texts and image in Lwuit, j2me

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-list

Basically I do like this

list = new List("Hello List", List.IMPLICIT, LIST_ITEMS, null);

...

list.append(titles,images);  // 1 text, 1 image

but, I wanna add descriptions to list item too. (titles, descriptions, images)

How can I do that? Do you have any example?

thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look here in the LWUIT blog.

Here you can see an example with some code

[LWUIT CellRender](http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html)

Answer (score 0):

While jmunoz's answer is 100% correct I'd like to add that you can just use MultiList if you use [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which is MUCH simpler and unlike LWUIT which is no longer supported by anyone Codename One has a strong following.